# Can we say that the circuit is a circuit of Nand element

Tags: transistors, mosfet, inverter

Can we say that this circuit is nand element ?

[image]

Comment: Looks more like `If X1 && X2 then Short-circuit the power supply`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have roughly the right idea but your circuit contains a few serious flaws:

Your schematic doesn't contain component designators, which makes it a hassle to talk about, which means I'll be brief.

The top of Q1 is directly connected to the power supply instead of a pullup.  When both Q1 and Q2 are on, all this will do is short the power supply.

There is no pullup for the top of Q3.  That node can therefore only be driven low, but nothing drives it high when Q3 is off.  It will therefore likely stay low due to stray capacitance.